# K-stability is invariant under D-equivalency

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, derived-categories, kahler-manifolds, mirror-symmetry

Kawamata conjectured that

Let $X$ and $Y$ be birationally equivalent smooth
projective varieties. Then the following are equivalent. We denote by
$D^b(Coh(X))$ the derived category of bounded complexes of coherent
sheaves on $X$

(1) There exists an equivalence of triangulated categories $D^b(Coh(X)) \cong
D^b(Coh(Y) )$.

(2) There exists a smooth projective variety $Z$ and birational morphisms
$f : Z\to  X$ and $ g : Z \to Y$ such that $f ^∗K_X ∼ g^∗K_Y $ (this means $X$ is a Fourier-Mukai partner of $Y$)

The main idea of the conjecture of "$K$-equivalence is equivalent with $D$-equivalence"

was that the Serre functor is invariant in the derived category of triangulated coherent sheaves and Serre functor is related to canonical divisor also, and so Kawamata gave such natural conjecture

In $dim=2 $ K-equivalency===> D-equivalency holds by a theorem of Zariski but for D-equivalency===>K-equivalency, Uehara gave a counterexample to this conjecture of Kawamata: Uehara, Hokuto: An example of Fourier-Mukai partners of minimal elliptic surfaces. Math. Res. Lett. 11 (2004), no. 2-3, 371–375

Now let  $D^b(Coh(X)) \cong
D^b(Coh(Y) )$ and $X$ admit Kähler-Einstein metric of negative Ricci curvature , then $Y$ admit also Kähler-Einstein metric of negative Ricci curvature (due to [Theorem 1.4](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1090351323))

> **I**:Now assume that $X$ and $Y$ are two smooth projective variety, $D^b(Coh(X)) \cong D^b(Coh(Y) )$ and $X$ is
>   $K$-stable, then $Y$ is $K$-stable? i.e does [K-stability](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.21578/abstract) is invariant
>   under D-equivalency?
>
> **II**: From Kawamata we know $D$-equivalence implies
>   the $K$-equivalence  for general type varieties, so my conjecture is that for 
>   Fano K-stable varieties $D$-equivalence implies
>   the $K$-equivalence

**Motivation: D-equivalency gave a lot of same information 
For example: Kawamata showed, If $K_X$ (resp. $−K_X$) is nef, then $K_Y$ (resp. $−K_Y$ ) is also nef, and
an equality on the numerical Kodaira dimension $ν(X) = ν(K_Y )$
(resp. $ν(X, −K_X) = ν(Y, −K_Y )$) holds**

Comment: Uehara's example is in dimension 2, I guess.

Comment: @Sasha , I think his conjecture is reduced to $K$-equivalency ===> $D$-equivalency and this holds for dimension 2 by Zariski theorem

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07370v1 is a recent survey, by Kawamata himself. I haven't read all the details yet, but it might give some answers, or pointers to the literature.

Comment: Isn't K-stability typically a property of Fano varieties? In the Fano case derived category determines X.

Comment: @EvgenyShinder , there is two $K$ here, of course, K-stability I mean for Fano varieties, but for Sasakian manifolds also we have this notion(which in my opinion is misleading since for Sasakian manifolds $Ric^T(\omega)=\Phi\omega^T$ where $\Phi$ is the leafwise constant and such $\Phi$ is a function which may not be constant)

Comment: Hassan: Are you aware that for smooth projective Fano varieties, if D^b(X) is equivalent to D^b(Y), then X and Y are isomorphic by the Reconstruction Theorem of Bondal and Orlov? So in this case K-stability is preserved by trivial reasons.

Comment: @EvgenyShinder, thank you, nice comment!, I was not aware of such amazing theorem(since I am new on this ground!). Is there any same theorem of Bondal and Orlov when $K_X$ is nef?

Comment: Hassan: No, Calabi-Yau varieties can have equivalent derived categories but they have $K_X = 0$, so it is nef.